# Change returned value in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working with real time viewing program that makes SQL queries (and let me edit bit of the code)

At the moment code is:

```
SELECT 
    [LogonName] AS [Logon name], 
    [LogonExtension] AS [Logon extension], 
    [VoiceReady] AS [Ready for Voice], 
    [CallState] AS [Call state]
FROM 
    [AgentPerformance]
WHERE 
    (AgentID IN (1, 2, 3))
```

This returns:

[image]

Now my question is that is there any way to change the returned "call state" values to let's say busy, free, handling etc... (there are 3 different values).

I have tried for example:

```
SELECT 
    [LogonName] AS [Logon name], 
    [LogonExtension] AS [Logon extension], 
    [VoiceReady] AS [Ready for Voice], 
    [CallState] AS [Call state]
FROM
    [AgentPerformance]
WHERE 
    (AgentID IN (1, 2, 3))

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN CallState = 0 THEN 'No'
       WHEN CallState = 1 THEN 'Yes
       ELSE 'Maybe'
    END AS kakaduu
FROM 
    AgentPerformance
```

But this didn't work for me.

Comment: SQL-Server or mysql

Comment: What means `didnt work for me`?

Comment: your case statement should be before where clause ..that ll work for you

Comment: Will there always be three Call State values or may the list be changed in the future?

Comment: Jens: i dont really know that answer, i am sorry :/
Toonice: there may be changes in the list in future

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` expression need to be in `SELECT` list along with another columns. second `SELECT` was incorrect syntax in your example.

So, try this:

```
SELECT [LogonName] AS [Logon name], [LogonExtension] AS [Logon extension], [VoiceReady] AS [Ready for Voice], [CallState] AS [Call state],
CASE 
    WHEN CallState = 0 then 'No'
    WHEN CallState = 1 then 'Yes'
    ELSE 'Maybe'
END
AS kakaduu
FROM [AgentPerformance]
WHERE   AgentID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Comment: Much better. A case expression returns a value. A case statement, used in stored procedures, is just conditional execution of code.

Comment: @JakeRahu And what is relationship between your question and the query with error at this image?

Comment: Seems like when i use the "case" the query (in this specific program)returns error, is there any other method i could try ?